# School project help: Connecting database to website and granting remote access

Tags: database

I'm working on a project at school where we have to create a small system for an RV retailer to track customers, vehicles, employees, inventory, and so on.

We've gotten to the point where we'll need to start coding pretty soon, but I'm having trouble figuring out the logistics of everything. For example, I know enough to build and use the website and database, but I don't have any idea on how to connect the two.

I know SQL fairly well. Enough to know what and where to look for the information, but I don't know enough about connecting my database to know what I'm looking for.

So what I'm looking for is a basic rundown on different options I can look and do some research on what would be best for our group.

I feel like there's a lot of information out there on how to do stuff, but I just don't have the basic information on why it's relevant and how and where to fully utilize it.

I hope this makes sense. Please let me know if there's anything I can do to help clear it up.

Comment: Sorry, SO is not a tutorial site.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the options of having a database-driven website is to use PHP.

It is a server-side scripting language, which is used to generate the dynamic content on the webpages. You can connect to the database, obtain user input using for example HTML forms, perform queries and display results on the webpage.

Essentially you build an application with a web-based user interface. PHP is supported on a vast majority of web hosting platforms.